FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY Performance impact on Select clause that returns 50 million records
I have to loop over 50 million rows in Oracle and do some processing. I get the rows using a simple Select and Order By query.
I first used a cursor-based JDBC reader to avoid getting all results at once but to fetch them as the loop moves ahead. However, the select query caused another issue where Oracle threw an error ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP probably because it is not able to hold the resultset of the select query in the TEMP space.
The other option I have is to do keyset pagination. To read the first page I will attach the following FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY clause at the end of the same Select query that I mentioned above.
Question: Will it work? Or I will get the same result because it has to run through and get all the results anyway and get the first 5000 rows?

Loop over 50 million rows means using a programming language. PL/SQL? Can't you do the things you want to do with plain SQL?

I need to make an API call as well to process the data which I do from the java process.

You can use SQL in an API call too. And just to give you an idea of what I am talking about: If I wanted to update all products with a status, when they occur in 50 million order position rows, I might update product set status = 'ordered' where product_id in (select product_id from order_position). So instead of using a programming language to loop through the 50 million order positions in order to do the processing of the products, I just use SQL, which is a million times faster. This is just an example of course. What are you doing with those 50M rows in your loop? Can't you use SQL, too?

Ok this is a dummy example because I can't put the actual code here because we arent allowed to. We do a lot more in the process before and after making the API call, requiring certain libraries with the logic built in. But I didn't know we can make an API call btw from PLSQL as I have used only for simple stuff ever.

An API is a collection of functions. You can write a bunch of PL/SQL functions and call this an API. Or use any other programming language that has an SQL interface (most do, I guess). And all I am saying is that with a database you don't usually process it via programming languages in loops, but rather use the set based SQL.

Ah by API call I meant a HTTP request to another service but I googled seems like that is also possible however would be a but cumbersome to call. But I get your point will keep in mind next time.

Pagination will not help.
You are receiving the ORA-01652 because your ORDER BY is using a workarea that has spilled from PGA over into temp space and your TEMP tablespace is not sufficiently large to hold the temp segments needed to complete the sort. 50 million rows and all the columns selected means some very large temp segments.
To resolve, you can do one of the following:

Request that your DBA enlarge the TEMP tablespace (a reasonable request)
Massively increase PGA usage (via pga_aggregate_target if the v$pgastat.global memory bound is < 1G) or by setting workarea policy to manual and defining sort_area_size yourself, but this is not a recommended method as you can easily use too much memory).
You can redefine the table as an IOT (index-organized table) with your PK on the column you wish to order by. Then the ORDER BY should do an ascending index scan without any sort operation at all. The downside is that this is an index scan, which means single block reads to follow the linked-list from leaf block to leaf block, so is less efficient than a direct path read of the whole segment.
Creating a normal index on a normal heap table can also avoid the sort, but it will perform very poorly, as every row will require a separate block read on the table segment, and at 50 million rows, that's going to be too much. At this volume you will want to do a full table scan, and as you need the sort operation, you will want it to be parallelized.
Ensure you are using parallelism (use a parallel hint with appropriate DOP). With a healthy DOP each PX slave gets its own PGA allocation (up to 1G each under automatic and 2G under manual policy) so you can use much more PGA memory for the sort (and hence less temp space) than you can with a serial process.
You can do your own "pagination" by using a WHERE predicate that gathers only a portion of the needed data and advances it programmatically. This reduces the input into the sort operation and can therefore be made to fit into your available TEMP space, but it is very inefficient as you have to keep rescanning the table with each query. It's always better to pull everything you need in one go. While you can remove this repeated scan by using an index, you are then back to the inefficiency mentioned above in #4.
Reduce the # of columns you are pulling. Do you really need them all? Any reduction in columns is going to reduce the size of the temp segment needed for the sort.
You might also consider just leaving the ORDER BY out altogether. Do you really need the results sorted? Most programmatic extracts don't.

In all the above, you'd do well to discuss with your DBA, who should know how much available memory is on the database host(s) for PGA, how much space available to extend TEMP, how much CPU availability there is to suggest an appropriate level of parallelism (DOP), etc.

Will attaching the FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY still get all the rows into the TEMP space or oracle will manage it in some way like mentioned in the other answers using only Ids etc.?

@humbleCoder, the FETCH NEXT.. merely does the computation for you, it doesn't change the underlying dynamics. If the column you are ordering by isn't indexed in alignment with the sort, you will do a full sort of 100% of the table on each execution, so pagination will hurt you because of the repeated sort. If it is indexed to avoid a sort, you'd avoid the sort even without the pagination, but see #4 above. You don't want to use an index at this volume. Too many single block reads. I myself have never found any real use for FETCH NEXT style pagination except for human user display.

DBA agreed to increase the TEMP space and am sticking with the cursor based reader to avoid all the issues with pagination.

It is better to run code close to data then run data to the code. As you experienced. Java is not suited for data manipulation. Database and SQL are.
Said that: "FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY" will encounter performance degradation with every page. E.g. first few pages will be lighting fast. Several last will load forever. This is because database engine will need to read 10.000.000 rows to return rows between 10.000.000 and 10.005.000. Every IO is costly. This is why it should matter.
Stable performance you can get with proper indexing and WHERE clause. Best explanation I found: https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way . Example is for PostgreSQL but will work with any database engine.

To process the data I call an external API. I did not mention it because I thought it would not be relevant but now that you have mentioned PLSQL I have mentioned it.

Yes for keyset pagination I am referring to the same article. Question is will the FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY with keyset pagination (which I mentioned in the initial question) also slow down after a few pages?

Reading 5000 rows will always take the same time. The crucial part is to quickly find row 1, 5001, 10001, ... and start reading 5000 you are interested in. This is why proper indexing is important. You do not want to read 49005000 rows and throw it to find 49005001 and read last 5000.

Yes, using keyset pagination will likely help you avoid the ORA-01652 error, because it doesn't require Oracle to load and sort all 50 million rows at once to fetch the first 5000 rows. Instead, it fetches rows in smaller batches based on a key (like an ID column) that you specify, which reduces the amount of temporary storage (TEMP space) needed.
Here's why it works better:
Efficiency: Keyset pagination only looks for rows after the last row it fetched, making it quicker and using less TEMP space.
Index Use: It works best when you have an index on the column you're ordering by. This way, Oracle can quickly find the next batch of rows without scanning the whole table.
However, make sure your query is well-optimized, and consider increasing your TEMP tablespace if you're still hitting limits. Also, ensure the columns you use for sorting and pagination are indexed to speed things up and reduce TEMP space usage further.

Is this AI generated?

do i look like an ai to you?
